# Prove tensor multiplication is bilinear

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading these online notes(http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/7752_Spring2010/lecture5.pdf), and on the bottom of page 2 the following exercise occurs.

Define tensor multiplication of two $R$-algebras $A$ and $B$ as:

$(a_1 \otimes b_1) \cdot (a_2 \otimes b_2) = a_1 a_2 \otimes b_1 b_2$.

Prove this is bilinear.

The first property of a function being bilinear is $(u+w) \cdot v = (u \cdot v) + (w \cdot v)$, so I tested the following:

$(a_1 \otimes b_1 + a_3 \otimes b_3) \cdot (a_2 \otimes b_2) = ???$

Tensor addition is not defined when one of the elements differs, so I am unsure of where to go beyond this.

Comment: The notes that you are reading specify that you extend the definition to arbitrary elements of $A \otimes_R B$ by distributivity.

Comment: The short answer is that the multiplication is defined as the bilinear extension of $(a_1 \otimes b_1) \cdot (a_2 \otimes b_2) := a_1 a_2 \otimes b_1 b_2$. So bilinearity is really built into the definition! The long answer is given in the marked duplicate thread. Namely, some things still have to be checked.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: The notes linked to define the multiplication as the _distributive_ extension of this formula -- in which case it still seems to require checking that it associates with scalar multiplication.